# Pandas - modify descriptives output from groupby.agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, aggregate

I wanted to get the mean, stp, skewness from any score column, while I grouped my data set be 2 other columns (group, block).
I used this code for it -

```
scores_list = ['A','B','C']
descriptive_agg = df.groupby(['group','block'])[scores_list].agg(['mean', 'std','skew'])
```

and got this dataFrame:

> ```
>   A   A   A   B   B   B   C   C   C
> ```

```
    mean    std skew    mean    std skew    mean    std skew
```

group   block
0   neg 26.76470588 54.79291496 6.069163775 3.098039216 1.170553749 0.114238196 1.738755233 0.611860454 1.063953504
0   neu 29.92   70.9644464  6.275474539 3.6 1.245399698 -0.039619494    1.906404475 0.568964543 0.561075178
1   neg 16.42391304 18.0702133  2.968326848 2.891304348 1.253185144 0.209586627 1.684455875 0.598785419 0.872917578
1   neu 16.92391304 18.49159815 2.951129818 3.5 1.172018077 -0.313988331    1.893045967 0.646930842 1.11778034

But I want to have a "score" column on the left, my expected output is:

> Score group   block   mean    std skew
> A   0   neg 26.76470588 54.79291496 6.069163775
> 0   neu 29.92   70.9644464  6.275474539
> 1   neg 16.42391304 18.0702133  2.968326848
> 1   neu 16.92391304 18.49159815 2.951129818

B   0   neg 3.098039216 1.170553749 0.114238196
0   neu 3.6 1.245399698 -0.039619494
1   neg 2.891304348 1.253185144 0.209586627
1   neu 3.5 1.172018077 -0.313988331

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.stack(0).reorder_levels([2,0,1]).sort_index()
print (df)
              mean      skew        std
A 0 neg  26.764706  6.069164  54.792915
    neu  29.920000  6.275475  70.964446
  1 neg  16.423913  2.968327  18.070213
    neu  16.923913  2.951130  18.491598
B 0 neg   3.098039  0.114238   1.170554
    neu   3.600000 -0.039619   1.245400
  1 neg   2.891304  0.209587   1.253185
    neu   3.500000 -0.313988   1.172018
C 0 neg   1.738755  1.063954   0.611860
    neu   1.906404  0.561075   0.568965
  1 neg   1.684456  0.872918   0.598785
    neu   1.893046  1.117780   0.646931
```

EDIT: If need replace duplicated values to empty strings:

```
#original index
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('A', 0, 'neg'),
            ('A', 0, 'neu'),
            ('A', 1, 'neg'),
            ('A', 1, 'neu'),
            ('B', 0, 'neg'),
            ('B', 0, 'neu'),
            ('B', 1, 'neg'),
            ('B', 1, 'neu'),
            ('C', 0, 'neg'),
            ('C', 0, 'neu'),
            ('C', 1, 'neg'),
            ('C', 1, 'neu')],
           )
```

---

```
df1 = df.index.to_frame(index=False)
df1.columns = [0,1,2]
m1 = df1[0].duplicated()
m2 = df1.duplicated(subset=[0,1])

df1[0] = df1[0].mask(m1, '')
df1[1] = df1[1].mask(m2, '')
print (df1)
    0  1    2
0   A  0  neg
1         neu
2      1  neg
3         neu
4   B  0  neg
5         neu
6      1  neg
7         neu
8   C  0  neg
9         neu
10     1  neg
11        neu
```

---

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)
df = df.rename_axis([None, None, None])
print (df)
              mean      skew        std
A 0 neg  26.764706  6.069164  54.792915
    neu  29.920000  6.275475  70.964446
  1 neg  16.423913  2.968327  18.070213
    neu  16.923913  2.951130  18.491598
B 0 neg   3.098039  0.114238   1.170554
    neu   3.600000 -0.039619   1.245400
  1 neg   2.891304  0.209587   1.253185
    neu   3.500000 -0.313988   1.172018
C 0 neg   1.738755  1.063954   0.611860
    neu   1.906404  0.561075   0.568965
  1 neg   1.684456  0.872918   0.598785
    neu   1.893046  1.117780   0.646931

   
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('A',  0, 'neg'),
            ( '', '', 'neu'),
            ( '',  1, 'neg'),
            ( '', '', 'neu'),
            ('B',  0, 'neg'),
            ( '', '', 'neu'),
            ( '',  1, 'neg'),
            ( '', '', 'neu'),
            ('C',  0, 'neg'),
            ( '', '', 'neu'),
            ( '',  1, 'neg'),
            ( '', '', 'neu')],
           )
```

Comment: Thank you! how can I keep these levels while exporting this df to CSV file ? for now it repeats the A in all the relevant 4 lines and repeats twice the groups number (in the 2 relevant lines)

Comment: @omer - it is expected, exaclty pandas working this way. Here are only not displayed repeated values. If check `print (df.index.tolist())` get real index values (same like written to file)

Comment: So how can I keep these levels while exporting this df to CSV file without repeated values in the first columns? thanks!

Comment: @omer - it is possible, but hack. Give e some time.

Comment: @omer - it is awful hack, check edited answer and how is changed `print (df.index)`

Comment: I got this error regarding m2: ---> 49 m2 = df1.duplicated(subset=[0,1])
     50 
     51 df1[0] = df1[0].mask(m1, '')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
   6195         diff = Index(subset).difference(self.columns)
   6196         if not diff.empty:
-> 6197             raise KeyError(diff)
   6198 
   6199         vals = (col.values for name, col in self.items() if name in subset)
KeyError: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')

Comment: @omer - answer was changed from `df1 = df.index.to_frame(index=False)` to `df1 = df.index.to_frame(index=False)
df1.columns = [0,1,2]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242732/discussion-between-omer-and-jezrael).